# How do I fix a bench that my dog chewed?

Tags: wood-repair, finish-selection

My dog thought this was a great idea, just need some advise on what type finish is on the wood currently? I'm going to sand the chewed part to start.

[image: The bench]

[image: Finish]

Comment: Going to be hard to tell if you don't provide any detail about the finish as it is hard to see from this photo. It could just be a stain... Anything you could try to describe it would help. Possible a close up would help as well. Are you asking just about the finish so you will know what you need to do to match it? You tagged wood-repair so are you also asking about fixing that corner as well?

Comment: Yes im trying to match it, i have added another picture to help. it looks like a stain to me. just not sure on what type i get?

Comment: Also how to repair and apply it

Comment: You could chew the other three corners to make it match. We had pre-worn jeans, dog-eaten furniture could become a trendy look, I suppose.

Comment: i wouldnt mind, its the wife going mad at  me like i have done it.

Comment: thats where i got it from http://www.houseoffraserforliving.co.uk/L021654.html

Comment: This looks like some rapidly grown (read as: cheap) needle wood both from the color, the wide rings, the many branches, and the fact that the dog would be able to bit off such a considerable chunk that easily (good luck doing that with oak), although a price upwards of 300 GBP isn't precisely what one would call "cheap". You will have no trouble finding a suitable piece of wood at every wood trader or in every home improvement store. **However**, matching the color will be a real pain, if possible at all. My best advice would be to remove the paint from the remaining table, and repaint it all.

Comment: Consider moving the table so that the chewed end is up against a wall.

Comment: Whatever you do, first get the dog's permission.

Answer (score 8):

Unless you want to refinish the whole table, this is really just going to come down to trial and error. Find some scrap wood, head down to the store to find some similar looking stains / oils / etc., and keep trying on scrap until you find something. You're probably not going to get the finish exactly right. You might also want to take a look through [these links](https://www.google.com/search?q=distressing%20wood) about distressing wood.

The damage is too extensive to fill it with putty, you'll probably want to remove that corner and replace it, or remove and replace that entire end piece.

Another thing you could try is changing the shape of the table a bit. E.g. maybe if you cut all corners at 45 degrees (to remove the chewed part and give the table a chamfered corner look), or cut a flat inch or two off the damaged side it could turn out well. But again you'll have to experiment with finishes, although you don't necessarily even have to match the finish... Another idea could be to cut the corners off then get creative, perhaps strip all the finish off just the sides and give it a different color, like a darker band around the edges or something, or even trim it with a different kind of wood. (As a bonus this'll also hide that splotch of gray stuff on the right in your picture.)

By the way, your dog will probably keep chewing it, you also might want to look into ways to change that behavior to prevent further damage in the future.

<sub>Warning: I don't actually know what I'm talking about and have limited experience.</sub>

Comment: `By the way, your dog will probably keep chewing it, you also might want to look into ways to change that behavior to prevent further damage in the future.`  Seconded.  Head off this behavior as soon as you can.

Comment: @Justin You don't necessarily have to match the finish... Another idea could be to cut the corners off then get creative, perhaps strip all the finish off just the sides and give it a different color, like a darker band around the edges or something, or even trim it with a different kind of wood.

Comment: Put some hot sauce on the chewed corner then invite the dog to have a gnaw again. Most likely he'll take a lick then run off, never to do it again. People feed dogs weird things these days, though, so YMMV. Pursue fixing the table after the dog has learned that it no longer tastes good.

Answer (score 1):

Round all the corners (to hide the fact that just one was damaged), and then finish the newly exposed wood? As long as all the corners match each other, folks will assume this was a deliberate design decision, even if they don't match the rest of the bench.